# #include errors detected in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code in my C++ project. I installed *Microsoft C/C++ Extension for VS Code*. I got the following error:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (`/path/to/project/file.cpp`) will be provided by the Tag Parser.

Comment: In Mac OS, installing xcode command line tools using `xcode-select --install` and then restarting vscode solved the problem for me.

Comment: For Linux users: Make sure you have `g++` installed.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The answer is here: [How to use C/Cpp extension and add includepath to configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_intellisense).

Click the light bulb and then edit the JSON file which is opened. Choose the right block corresponding to your platform (there are `Mac`, `Linux`, `Win32` – ms-vscode.cpptools version: 3). Update paths in `includePath` (matters if you compile with VS Code) or `browse.paths` (matters if you navigate with VS Code) or both.

Thanks to @Francesco Borzì, I will append his answer here:

You have to <kbd>Left</kbd>  click on the bulb next to the squiggled code line.

> If a `#include` file or one of its dependencies cannot be found, you can also click on the red squiggles under the include statements to view suggestions for how to update your configuration.

[image]

Comment: Regarding `includePath` and `browse.path`: your explanation is not quite right.  *Both* are used while browsing, neither is used during compilation.  See the [VSCode FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_what-is-the-difference-between-includepath-and-browsepath) and another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734835/2659307) of mine.

Comment: What do I do if the include error is a native library? VS Code is complaining about `#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>`

Comment: 'Add to "includePath"' is not an option on my editor, which does have the C/C++ extension. Could I get some insight as to why?

Comment: @EthanGroat, perhaps you have disabled error squiggles? Could you check options `C_Cpp.errorSquiggles` and `C_Cpp.default.enableConfigurationSquiggles` in settings?

Comment: The problem is, I am not getting the option to add to the include path.

Comment: @BugHunterUK is it possible to add/change `includePath` manually? See this answer for further guidance https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139743/7769052.

Comment: This is the correct solution!!!!!

Comment: How update paths in includePath ?

Answer (score 186):

Close and re-open Visual Studio Code.

Comment: simple and to the point! Is there any shortcut like invalidate cache and rebuilt indexes?

Comment: But why does it work?????????????

Comment: It will also show an error if there is an include error in the included file itself. =)
(This is why I am here. An hour wasted.)

Comment: This actually works.  But given how well vscode is engineered, it needs to be explained - why?

Answer (score 88):

If you are working with `cmake-tools` and the error messages says something is wrong with the `configurationProvider`, then you have 2 options:

1. Use `ms-vscode.cpptools` instead of `ms-vscode.cmake-tools`
2. Define the headers in `CMakeLists.txt`

### Option 1: Use `ms-vscode.cpptools` instead of `ms-vscode.cmake-tools`.

1. Open ***c_cpp_properties.json***. (windows key on windows or cmd key on mac + shift + p, enter "c/c++ edit configurations" and chose 'json'.
2. Enter ***ms-vscode.cpptools*** as value for ***configurationProvider*** instead of *ms-vscode.cmake-tools* or whatever you have.

How it should look like after the replacement of ***configurationProvider***:

[image]

One other important configuration is the include path. The assumption is that you have this configuration right. May be like following

[image]

### Option 2: Define the headers in `CMakeLists.txt`

When `configurationProvider` is set to `ms-vscode.cmake-tools` in `c_cpp_properties.json`, VS Code uses the include information defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` instead of reading the `includePath` configs in VS Code.

So you need to setup the include path correctly:

1. using the [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) command (rather than the target_include_directories command) to define the headers
2. Configure the project to reflect the change happened in the previous step.

Comment: Before making this change, check if a restart of vscode helps.

Comment: not work at all, the `include_directories`  of CMAKE need demos

Comment: I tried all answers below but nothing helped. I was working on a file called `C.cpp` that is imported into `B.cpp` and was then imported into `main.cpp`. Opening `main.cpp` in the editor fixed all issues.

Comment: Finally, a solution. Adding `include_directories` in CMakeLists.txt worked for me. I hope it doesn't mess up with my otherwise "modern" CMake code (targets, etc).

Answer (score 34):

- Left mouse click on the bulb of error line
- Click `Edit Include path`
- Then this window popup

[image]

- Just set `Compiler path`

Comment: After above steps, please restart the vs code.

Comment: I have this set to `/usr/bin/g++`, IntelliSense mode set to linux-gcc-x64, and the include path set to include `${workspaceFolder}/**` and I still get include path errors. I do have GCC and G++ installed. I have the same problem with Clang.

Comment: Simple & Starightforward! Solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I'm on a Macbook M1 Pro, and I had red squiggly error lines all over my C++ files. To solve, I did this:

1. Open Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for `intelliSenseEngine`
3. Change "C_Cpp: Intelli Sense Engine" from `Default` to `Tag Parser`

alternatively, you could create a `.vscode` folder in your project root, and then create a `settings.json` with the content of

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine" : "Tag Parser"
}
```

ideally, you should have a `c_cpp_properties.json` file in the same folder with the right settings as well.

Note: I got this idea from Github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1144#issuecomment-362012873).

Comment: Why does this work though?

Answer (score 17):

I ended up here after struggling for a while, but actually what I was missing was just:

> If a #include file or one of its dependencies cannot be found, you can also click on the red squiggles under the include statements to view suggestions for how to update your configuration.

[image]

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_intellisense

Comment: What if there are no suggestions?

Comment: If there is a lightbulb, there are suggestions

Answer (score 10):

The error message "Please update your includePath" does not necessarily mean there is actually a problem with the `includePath`.  The problem may be that VSCode is using the wrong compiler or wrong IntelliSense mode.  I have written instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742056/2659307) on how to troubleshoot and align your VSCode C++ configuration with your compiler and project.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your `c_cpp_properties.json` file by searching from settings.There you might see the following code

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Change the compiler path as below

```json
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
```

Comment: If you don't have g++ installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install g++`

Answer (score 6):

I was trying a hello world program, and this line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

was underlined green. I tried:

1. Deleting the line
2. Re-writing the line
3. Clicking the yellow bulb and choosing to update

fixed the error warning. i don't know if it fixed the actual problem. But then i'm compiling via a linux VM on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer would be opening VS Code in remote WSL, if you going to compile files with g++. Just close your VS Code and open WSL and type `code .` After that the File Explorer shows that VS Code is now running in the context of WSL with the title bar **[WSL: Ubuntu]**. But make sure you'd installed the `GNU compiler tools and the GDB debugger` on WSL.

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl

Answer (score 2):

after you install the c/c++ extension, two files are created inside .vscode folder.

open c_cpp_properties.json file and paste this key-value pair inside configuration object.(if it doesn't already exists)

```
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode-cpptools"
```

if it does already exists in the object, see if the value part is `ms-vscode-cmaketools`. if such it is, replace that existing line with above line.

this will allow you to execute your cpp files along with c files.

Answer (score 2):

Faced this issue with Mac M1 chip and was unable to compile and run a .cpp file which had `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` header.

Upon investigation I got to know that the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header is not part of the C++ standard; rather, it's a header file specific to the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC). Apple Clang, being a different compiler, may not include this header by default.

- So, specific to your project configurations, you can set the `compilerPath` to point at the path where you have installed the `GNU g++ compiler`.
- To find out if you have ever installed GNU gcc compiler with homebrew before, use the command `brew info gcc`. This will give out the version of the compiler if it exists with homebrew list.
- Use the command `which g++-{your-specific-version}` eg. `which g++-13`, in my case this gave the output of  `/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13` which I then used to set the compilerPath in C/C++ Configuration file as well as the `tasks.json` file attached below.

```json
//for c++17 build
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "compile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-o",
                "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": false
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13 -std=c++17 -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension} ${file} && ./${fileBasenameNoExtension} < input.txt > output.txt",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- For **[Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)**:

1.Install  [Mingw-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)

2.Then Edit **environment variables** for your account "C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin"

3.Reload

- For **MAC**

  1.Open search ,command + shift +P, and run this code “c/c++ edit configurations (ui)”

  2.open file c_cpp_properties.json and update the includePath from "${workspaceFolder}/**" to "${workspaceFolder}/inc"

Answer (score 1):

If someone have this problem, maybe you just have to install build-essential.

```
apt install build-essential
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, using Ubuntu, I just had to install gcc to solve this issue.

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

Then, set the compiler path to gcc. Go to your c_cpp_properties.json file, set:

```
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error on my Mac by just clicking on the Edit "include path settings" and changing the compiler path to `/usr/bin/clang`.

Answer (score 0):

After closing and reopening VS, this should resolve.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did not need to close the whole VS-Code, closing the opened file (and sometimes even saving it) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck removing the comments from c_cpp_properties.json in the .vscode folder. Comments aren't permitted in json files by default and you can't simply rename it .jsonc. Referenced [In VS Code, disable error "Comments are not permitted in JSON"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834825/in-vs-code-disable-error-comments-are-not-permitted-in-json)

Answer (score 0):

My header file was in `include/head.h`, code in `src/code.cpp`. I wrote

`#include "head.h"`

and got this error. Changing it to

`#include "../include/head.h"`

fixed it.

Comment: `#include '../include/head.h` shouldn't even compile. It should result in an error `missing terminating ' character`. Did you mean `#include "../include/head.h"`?

Comment: @banan3'14 Good catch, I was fooled into thinking it was there due to the code block markdown syntax ending in `. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, once I removed `configurationProvider` node and set
`cStandard` and `cppStandard` to default values:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test",
                "/opt/qt5/include/QtCore",
                "${workspaceFolder}/test"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "${default}",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Windows:

1. Please add this directory to your environment variable(Path):

> C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\

2. For Include errors detected, mention the path of your include folder into

> "includePath": [
>   "C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/include/" ]

, as this is the path from where the compiler fetches the library to be included in your program.

Answer (score -1):

In case you've copied and pasted code into your new file in VS Code

Please delete `#include <iostream>` and try to build again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30557105)