# In VS Code, disable error "Comments are not permitted in JSON"

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, comments

I sometimes use Visual Studio Code to edit JSON files that include comments. VS Code displays an error saying, "Comments are not permitted in JSON." It would be nice to disable that error message (without having to remove the comments.)

[image]

Comment: Fwiw, it [looks like @jass wants to know what app you used for your screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67292768/1028230) -- asking b/c they don't have enough rep to leave a comment, which I think might be why they duped an answer and posted. (Perhaps not technically a legit comment, but I've seen worse. `;)`).

Answer (score 427, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Click on the letters JSON in the bottom right corner. (A drop-down will appear to "Select the Language Mode.")
2. Select "Configure File Association for '.json'..."

[image]

3. Type `jsonc` and press Enter.

[image]

If you only want to disable the error message for a single file, skip step #2.

Comment: If you want to use the Command Palette or assign a keyboard shortcut, this is called "Change Language Mode"

Comment: is it possible to config this via comment at the beginning of a file? just like control comments of jslint.

Comment: @Wayou No, you can't configure that with a comment. At least, not that I know of in VSCode.

Comment: In User Settings, you can default all .json files to JSON with Comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48773989/4642023

Comment: you got me on right track

Answer (score 121):

Add this to your User Settings:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.json": "jsonc"
},
```

If you don't already have a user settings file, you can create one. Hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>** or **<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>** (that's a comma) to open your settings, then hit the *Open Settings (JSON)* button in the upper right. It looks like this: [image: the button's icon; a page with a little curved arrow over it]

Comment: Found this useful, but I also agree with v-andrew - usually want to keep the jsonc separate from the normal json files.

Where I found this useful though is vendor supplied files - like `rush.json` which the vendor supplies with comments.  In that case use a file association like:
`"files.associations": { "rush.json": "jsonc" }`

no need to wildcard it.

Answer (score 35):

Just rename file to `test.jsonc`

Reasons to use `JSONC` and not to allow comments in the regular `JSON` files are:

1. It will separate your file from real JSON files
2. It is not going to bite you in the back when you add comment to a file where validation has to be applied, but you forget to remove comments because there is no error message.
3. It is going to work out of the box on any setup without "tuning" someone's else VS Code.

Answer (score -3):

[image: enter json config demo in this picture]

**answer**: enter  `associations`  in VScode setting, add item `*.json`  `jsonc`.

*btw: What is your screenshot software? pleassssse tell me, and which font on screenshot img？*

Comment: I think your answer is probably a [dupe of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48773989/1028230)... I'm guessing you posted so you could ask the question even though you don't have enough rep for a comment? I'll go ask and maybe you can delete this?