# External libraries dont work (C/C++) visual studio code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, libraries

I am a freshman that attends a CS college. I am learning C and we have to use some external libraries . While no problems apppear when I include those libraries,when im using a library specific syntax(for example GetInteger) vs code outputs: " undefined reference to  GetInteger"

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "genlib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int age;
   printf("Whats your age?\n");
   
   age=GetInteger();
   printf("Your age is %d",age);
   return 0;
}
```

Those are my c_ccp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**","C:\\MinGW\\include","C:\\MinGW\\lib","C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\6.3.0"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My launch.sjon:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            
            "args":["-g", "-o", "out.exe", "main.cpp", "test.c"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "\\usr\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

and my tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }]
}
```

Comment: Did you link your library?

Comment: Where is your library mentioned in any of the files you have posted?

Comment: You need to include the library paths in your project. And also link with the libraries (if they are not include only libraries (i.e.: they get compiled with your project and there are not any .dll/.lib/.so).

Comment: how do I link my libraries? I am sorry im very new to this. What info do you want me to provide. I ll try my best

Comment: Your school or instructor should be giving you basic information about using the build tools, including instructions on how to tell the build system to include specific libraries when linking.

Comment: My school is using codeblocks but for some reason it is bugged so my instructor told me to go to visual studio code

Comment: Your bug is in your tasks.json. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries)

Comment: please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: This looks quite weird to me: `"miDebuggerPath": "\\usr\\bin\\gdb.exe",` it's a mix of unix and windows..