# Urlmon header in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, urlmon

so im trying to download a file from a url link using URLDownloadToFile, and that needs the urlmon
when i include urlmon.h and the urlmon.lib it cant find the headers.
I am using visual studio code, anyone know how could i get the header and the library?

Comment: You probably have to edit your tasks.json

Comment: ok how do i do that and what i add in it?

Comment: The msdn documentation says you have to link to `urlmon.lib` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms775123(v=vs.85))

Comment: How you link depends on what compiler you selected. For gcc its probably adding `"-lurlmon,"` to your compilers args:

Comment: This question has examples on how to link to libraries with VSCode: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries)

Comment: I am using a extension and not the built in visual studio code c++ build and debug. i added the compiler flag -lurlmon and ran with it but i am still getting errors that URLdownloadfile is undefined

Comment: Are you talking about the code-runner extension? I don't use that. There is a tag for that you can add to your question.

Comment: no, i use compile & run. You can edit the flags and i added that flag but i still get the same error