# How can I fix this error on visual studio code?

Tags: c, raylib

I'm new to C and i'm trying to create a window in raylib, my  compiler is clang, but it keeps on giving me an error that i need help fixing , here's my code :

```
#include "raylib.h"

int main(void)
{
    const int screenWidth = 800;
    const int screenHeight = 450;

    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "raylib  example - basic window");

    SetTargetFPS(60);               
    
    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose())    
    {
        BeginDrawing();
            ClearBackground(RAYWHITE);
            DrawText("Congrats! You created your first window!", 190, 200, 20, LIGHTGRAY);
        EndDrawing();
    }
    
    CloseWindow();        

    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BeginDrawing", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_ClearBackground", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_CloseWindow", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_DrawText", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_EndDrawing", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_InitWindow", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_SetTargetFPS", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
  "_WindowShouldClose", referenced from:
      _main in raytest-8c368e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

How to fix this???

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to link with the raylib library. Add `-lraylib` when compiling.

Comment: Man Ted, almost like you've run across this type question once or twice before `:)` For further discussion see [VSCode c++ task.json include path and libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52910102/3422102)

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that i'm on Mac os and have raylib on the same  folder.  It just says `Admins-MacBook-Pro-2:C admin$ -lraylib`.

Comment: `clang -o raytest raytest.c -L . -lraylib`

Comment: Thanks! I suppose you didn't mean to put "raytest",  because it says no such files or directory when I have  it, but when I remove it, it says no input files.