# VS Code thinks first line of any file is an #include error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The first line of any file in my workspace is treated as if it's an include error. It has a red squiggly line and on hover says

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit.
```

Also if the first line is a multiline comment then the second line (of the comment) has the error.

How do I fix this? Clearly comments can't have errors.

Edit: My include path is set, obviously I did that before asking this question. But even if I hadn't set it, this error still shouldn't be occurring on non-#include statements and even *in comments*!

Comment: Does it happen on every file in any language? Does it happen in empty files as well?

Comment: Just googled it. I'd say it's [an issue with C++](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1863) and you need to, well, set your includePath ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#include errors detected in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Include path is set, only happens in (most) C++ files. I'm not using MinGW or Windows so your linked GitHub issue isn't relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've added the [tag:c++] tag so hopefully the question can be found by someone familiar with the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this (*temporarily*) by clicking the light bulb when hovering over the squiggle error. Then, clicking 'Edit "includePath" setting'. Next, clicking the link in left side of the displayed page that says:

> Switch to the c_cpp_properties.json file by clicking on the file link
> or using the command: C/C++: Edit configurations (JSON)

I then changed nothing in that file and saved it. It seems that by simply existing, the includePath issue is resolved and the squiggles disappeared.

I think this is likely a bug in VSCode where saving the json file "c_cpp_properties.json" populates "includePath"

**Once you restart VSCode, the same thing with the squiggles will happen again.** You can open the file "c_cpp_properties.json" and immediately click to save it, and the squiggles will again disappear.