# #include errors detected. Please update your includePath

Tags: visual-studio

I am working with Visual Studio Code, and when I am starting to code in C, an error message shows up:

> include errors detected. Please update your `includePath`. Squiggles
>   are disabled for this translation unit
>   *(C:\Users\user\Desktop\c2\main.c)*

Any help?

Comment: This is might be a duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode/46321822

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#include errors detected in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode)

Comment: no i tried them all but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case you tend to tranfer your code from one system to another, some things may get messed up.

VSCODE creates a specific folder when you start a new project called -you guessed it- "vscode" where some useful information about JSON and the compiler are stored. If you move your project to a different pc and try to open it via vscode, it is likely that the info stored in VSCODE-directory will not apply to this system.

In my case, I had a path like: "Users/user1..." in a system that did not have any user named user1 so i had to configure the VSCODE directory or even delete it altogether and let VSCODE create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Before this, I've got the same problem too, but the problem had been solved after I reset my entire vs code setting.

It's very simple to reset it:

1. To open the Settings editor, navigate to File > Preferences > Settings. You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P (Windows, Linux Ctrl+Shift+P)) with Preferences: Open Settings or use the keyboard shortcut (⌘, (Windows, Linux Ctrl+,)).
2. Press it and type "Open user settings(Json)"
3. After that, delete all contents of the file and add a set off curly braces
   "{}"
4. And then save it by press "X" button.

That's all. Fyi, this works for me. Idk if this works for certain people. If you want to know more go  to this link https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/reset-vscode-to-default-settings