# Include errors detected VS Code, WSL, but program works

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

VS Code cannot see `pthread.h` but the program compiles and works fine, it is just the fact that the file appears as red, pointing to that line. I am working on Windows 11, using WSL, with the C/C++ extension enabled. It's a really annoying bug, for which I found no fix. [image]

Comment: Did you try to update your IncludePath as the message tells you?

Comment: See [VS Code: Customize default settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#include errors detected. Please update your includePath in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323394/include-errors-detected-please-update-your-includepath-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: My include path is  ${workspaceFolder}/**, how should I change it to aggregate pthread.h?

Comment: You only include files from your workspace. There is barely a chance this will include compiler headers. Where is your include folder? Where is `pthread.h` located? Find and add that folder.

Comment: I didn't download pthread.h, and since my program works well I think it's downloaded by default. I will search for it and add it.

Comment: That is not strange at all if you look at the details: VS Code is an editor. It tries to see what the compiler might see. The compiler is a different program with different default folders. It knows where to look, at least for the standard headers. The editor does not unless you tell it.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the *actual text* instead.

Comment: Copying the path and including it does not work, vscode doesn't see it: https://imgur.com/a/KHEAWN4
Any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: I think the problem is generated by the wsl, since I don't have the actual tools needed for c++ on my host, and it seems that vs code cannot see files inside the wsl.

Comment: write the include paths as if you work on the remote, not how the local VSC sees the remote, local VSC is just a viewer of the remote VSC, the C language server runs on the remote, change the setting files on the remote

Answer (score 0):

Fix: installing pthread.h on host using [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html)
The vcpkg folder needs to be added to path.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do it. It should be possible to configure VSC to use the files on the remote directly.