# Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath "/usr/bin/gcc". Using "cl.exe" instead

Tags: c++, path, configuration, intellisense, compiler-warnings

I am doing flutter devlopement and in that there are some modules of c++. These were the automatically generated files of c++. When i open the project in vscode it shows this message in output. I have installed c++ compiler mingw64 and included path in the environment variables.

I tried changing configurations of c++ intellisense.
As per this..
[#include errors detected. Please update your includePath in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323394/include-errors-detected-please-update-your-includepath-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: This simply means that in your c_cpp_properties.json file you have the `compilerPath` setting `/usr/bin/gcc` and this is not correct for your computer. Simply edit the file and change the setting to wherever your compiler actually is. Since you are on Windows this will presumably be something like `"C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"` but obviously only you know the correct setting.

Comment: There might be some missing info from your comment - When I reload windows in VS Code (on Windows 10), I get 6 errors saying `[6/21/2023, 9:06:19 AM] Unable to resolve configuration with compilerPath: "C:\Tools\ARM_GCC\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe"`  even though that path to my gcc compiler is correct (I can run it from cmd or powershell jus fine).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with a different compiler (ti-cgt-arm) and I ended up setting

`"compilerPath": ""`

in the corresponding configuration in `c_cpp_properties.json` and then added all necessary entries in `"includePath":` (to fix the intellisense errors for `#include`s). I found the hints in the [VS Code CPP documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference):

> compilerPath (optional) The full path to the compiler you use to build your project, for example /usr/bin/gcc, to enable more accurate IntelliSense. The extension will query the compiler to determine the system include paths and default defines to use for IntelliSense.

> Putting "compilerPath": "" (empty string) will skip querying a compiler. This is useful if a specified compiler doesn't support the arguments that are used for the query, as the extension will default back to any compiler it can find (like Visual C). Leaving out the compilerPath property does not skip the query.

Apparently, when the compiler doesn't respond to VS Code as it expects (because the compiler doesn't support the arguments passed by VS Code), VS Code decides to use a fallback compiler.