# "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit" problem in Flutter and Firebase project

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, firebase-authentication

I set up my Flutter application in early August and implemented Google login with Firebase by mid August. I have not changed anything related to Firebase Auth since then, and my GitHub says the Firebase folder has the last commit in around early September. The same goes for Android, iOs, and other folders. I am sure I have not messed up anything, so the problem is not on my part. Today I logged out and now when I choose the account to log in, on three different devices, I can not log in and the reloading icon just keeps spinning. From September until now I have logged out and logged in dozens of times, but now it does not work. Nothing also appears in my vscode output or debug console. Is this a common uccurence with Firebase? Have you ever encountered such a problem?

Edit:

The problem seems to be related to the question below.

[#include errors detected. Please update your includePath in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323394/include-errors-detected-please-update-your-includepath-in-visual-studio-code)

My screen: https://i.imgur.com/qlj6UEs.jpg

Flutter message: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

Do I have to address the problem if I am not making apps for windows. My project is Flutter and I know nothing about C++. I can not find a question here adressing this problem in Flutter project.

My generated_plugin_registrant.cc file:

```
#include "generated_plugin_registrant.h"

#include <cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_plugin_c_api.h>
#include <firebase_auth/firebase_auth_plugin_c_api.h>
#include <firebase_core/firebase_core_plugin_c_api.h>
#include <flutter_tts/flutter_tts_plugin.h>

void RegisterPlugins(flutter::PluginRegistry* registry) {
  CloudFirestorePluginCApiRegisterWithRegistrar(
      registry->GetRegistrarForPlugin("CloudFirestorePluginCApi"));
  FirebaseAuthPluginCApiRegisterWithRegistrar(
      registry->GetRegistrarForPlugin("FirebaseAuthPluginCApi"));
  FirebaseCorePluginCApiRegisterWithRegistrar(
      registry->GetRegistrarForPlugin("FirebaseCorePluginCApi"));
  FlutterTtsPluginRegisterWithRegistrar(
      registry->GetRegistrarForPlugin("FlutterTtsPlugin"));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the version of firebase dependencies?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @PrathamSarankar, I made an edit to my post. Yes I updated all of them.