# Problems with includePath in VS Code (C)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch over VS code for my C programming however I am having problems with include statements. I have installed all the correct extensions (i.e C/C++) however when I start my program with "#include <stdio.h>" it is underlined by a red squiggle line.

It tells me there is a "#include error detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit". I am an amateur programmer and have no idea how to solve this. Any help anyone can give would awesome! I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45583488/5495101

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#include errors detected in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode)

Comment: Boy there seems to be several Dups on this one. I flagged this as a dup, because it is, but that should also help you to find a solution, there are already several good answers out there. Click on the link I provided above. Another good answer, which I also flagged as a dup, can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910102/vscode-c-task-json-include-path-and-libraries

Comment: The best resource for this though is a MP4 that VSCode created. This is a great resource that is clear concise and will get you rolling my friend: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/introvideos-cpp#_configure-c-intellisense  -- ___"Happy coding!"___