# #include errors detected in vs code for c lang

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include-path

I don't know what to do
please can any one help me
I'm trying to use c in vs code for the first time

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
   printf("Hello, World!");
}
```

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMfUd.png)

Comment: you can use C/C++ extension in vs code and for more information [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode)

Comment: Have you installed a C compiler?