# #include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I keep getting three errors when I try including a header file that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <"maximum.h"> // *** Header file that is getting the three errors ***
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
#include errors detected. based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting.
cannot open source file ""maximum.h""
'"maximum.h"' file not found
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode/68139743#68139743), is a link to a solution I tried out. That didn't solve the problem for me. Could anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever tutorial/reference told you to `#include` *anything* using *both* `<>` and `""` delimiters at the same time, burn it. Use one or the other, not both, depending on where the header is located (<system> vs "user").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find file `.../"maximum.h"` which obviously in not existing.

Use either `<maximum.h>` which first will search your file inside compiler directories or `"maximum.h"` which first will search near your current file.