# Vs code include path error on mac i cant find the solution online

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im using vs code on mac and the `#include <stdio.h>`  is error. It says “please update your include path”.

I tried to look it up online and still cant find the answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#include errors detected in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode)