# in C on VS code, how do I fix "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath" on Mac?

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, include-path

Error when using #include:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.

new to C, I can't get this error fixed and I don't know how it occurred, given that I didn't touch VC code settings at all. **What do I update it to?**

I checked a bunch of the existing questions about this issue like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583473/include-errors-detected-in-vscode), but I'm still unsure what to do because 1. I don't have some of the fields they suggested editing and 2. I’m working with C on Mac not C++ on Windows. Maybe it's the same, but I don't want to mess anything up.

Here is how my c_cpp_properties.json looks:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": ""
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and this is my IntelliSense Configurations
[image]

Comment: It would help if you told us *what* header files you have problem with, and where they are located.

Comment: And you have read [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude all header files. anything following #include gives me an error. I'm not sure where each one is located. I never had to change their location or the setting in general on VScode, so I wouldn't be able to tell you where they are or were located. it used to work fine, until yesterday when all of a sudden i started to get this error. the only thing I would've done that maybe messed up VS code settings was updating my macOS from Catalina to Ventura

Comment: Please read the documentation. Look at their example `c_cpp_properties.json` file. It contains some data in both the `macFrameworkPath` and `compilerPath` setting variables.